# Javascript form validation for custom browser extensions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, url, meteor

I want to let users create custom urls for group pages, and I'm trying to find the best way to restrict them to appropriate characters: pretty much just numbers, letters, or a hyphen.

I've built a form that lets them create a custom extension, and I know how to require unique documents in MongoDB, but what's the best way to create the required validations (or whatever it's called)? Could it be something like this, replacing the "something"?

Is there anything else I should consider?

```
function isValidExtension(val, field) {
  if (something) {
    return true;
  } else {
    Alerts.add('forbidden characters found', 'warning');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I figured out.

```
function isValidExtension(val, field) {
  if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/.test(val)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    Alerts.add('forbidden characters found', 'warning');
    return false;
  }
}
```